# gulp-connect plugins connect.reload() not refreshing browser for following angular setup

Tags: angularjs, gulp, gulp-connect

Folder structure of the angular app:

```
src
  client
    app
    assets
    index.html
  server
gulpfile.js
```

I have following task to create a dev server and trying to watch changes in index.html and in case of change I'm trying to reload the page

```
gulp.task('dev-server',function(){
  connect.server({
    port: 8888,
    livereload: true
  });
  gulp.watch('./src/client/app/index.html', ['reload']);
});

gulp.task('reload', function(){
  gulp.src('./src/client/index.html')
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

Current behaviour: running dev-server task creates a server. And on change in index.html is trigerring the reload task as expected. However browser does not get auto refreshed.

Question 1: How to make the browser window/specific tab auto refresh on change?

Question 2: when I launch localhost:8888, it actually opens the folder structure in the browser and from there on I have to navigate to index.html manually. How do I launch index.html directly?

Answer (score 1):

With `fallback: './src/client/index.html'` you could fix the direct opening of `index.html`. But the livereload was also not working in my local setup. Not sure what's wrong.

I would recommend to use [`browser-sync`](https://www.browsersync.io/) as your livereload dev server because `gulp-connect` seems deprecated.

Then you could create a gulp file like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var reload = browserSync.reload;

// watch files for changes and reload
gulp.task('serve', function() {
browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'src/client'
    }
 });

 gulp.watch(['*.html', 'styles/**/*.css', 'scripts/**/*.js'], {cwd: 'src/client'}, reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```